# perl - print sql row

Tags: linux, shell, perl

I want to print all sql result of my perl script, I've connected to the database and I want to show the result of my sql query :

```
MySQL("SELECT * FROM test");

# define subroutine to submit MySQL command
 sub MySQL
 {   
     #Connect to the database.
     my $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:database=database;host=ip",
     "login", 'password',
     {'RaiseError' => 1});

     my $query = $_[0];  #assign argument to string

     my $sth = $prepare($query);   #prepare query

     $sth->execute();   #execute query

     while (my @row = $sth->fetchrow_array)
        {
            print "@row\n";
        }
}
```

I have this errors :

```
Global symbol "$prepare" requires explicit package name at test3.pl line 34.
syntax error at test3.pl line 34, near "$prepare("
Global symbol "$sth" requires explicit package name at test3.pl line 36.
Execution of test3.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

Comment: Please read the [DBI documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI) for how to use `prepare`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this line:

```
my $sth = $prepare($query);
```

to

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($query);
```

and don't forget to close the `$sth` and `$dbh` handles after the while loop with:

```
$sth->finish;
$dbh->disconnect;
```

Answer (score 0):

In your last post there is only one reference to **e** in the following comment

```
#INNER JOIN events e ON (e.objectid = t.triggerid)
```

probably it is better to use syntax `INNER JOIN events as e ON (e.objectid = t.triggerid)` -- more readable

Comment: Well, you have changed your question [portion of it is removed now]. In original question you had added 'extra' question where in SQL statement you had **е** field commented out -- what caused an error. It was a reason why I have pointed you to the cause of the error.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have a database at hand available right at this moment. The following example should work in theory. I have replaced **fetch_array** on **fetch_hashref** the output will provide information about each row

`ddddd column=value\tcolumn=value\t...`

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $query = qq(SELECT * FROM tb_test);

db_query($query);

sub db_query {
    my $query = shift;

    my $count = 1;

    my $dbh = DBI->connect(
                    "DBI:mysql:database=database;host=ip",
                    "login", 'password',
                    {'RaiseError' => 1}
              );

    my $sth = $dbh->prepare($query);

    $sth->execute();

    while ( my $row = $sth->fetchrow_hashref() ) {

            print "%5d ", $count++; # rows count

            while( my($k,$v) = each %$row ) { print "%s=%s\t",$k,$v; }

            print "\n"; # we done with current row
    }

    $sth->finish;
    $dbh->disconnect;
}
```

You need look into [DBI](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI) documentation to get full understanding how it works.